# Django models dynamic choices

Tags: python, django, django-models

Lately I've been playing with Django 1.4.3 (Python 2.7) and I needed a model field to have it's choices loaded dynamically.
Basically, I needed the possibility to register a possible choice option from somewhere.

First I thought:

> Baah, it's gonna be easy. Python passes lists by reference

It doesn't went that well...

Here are the snippets that worked for me:

**models.py**

```
class CategoryModels:
    def __init__(self):
        self.category_models = [
            ['dummy', 'dummy']
        ]

    def register(self, model, label=None):
        if label == None:
            label = model.split('.').pop()
        self.category_models.append([model, label])

    def get_models(self):
        return self.category_models

category_models = CategoryModels()

class Category(models.Model):
    MODEL_CHOICES = category_models.get_models()

    name  = models.CharField(blank=False, unique=True, max_length=30)
    model = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=30, choices=MODEL_CHOICES)
```

**admin.py**

```
import app
app.models.category_models.register('app.models.Entity')
app.models.category_models.register('app.models.OtherModel')
```

It works, but... Note, that the list contains some 'dummy' entry. The weird part is, without the 'dummy' entry it does not work (You just get a regular input field).
I've already did some research on this topic and found other solutions with lazy loading, etc.
But this one seems to be the easiest one, and most clear.
I just wonder why without the 'dummy' entry it does not work? Why the choices are empty.
It also breaks if you do something like:

```
def get_models(self):
        return self.category_models.reverse()
```

Does it have something to do with Python or Django mechanisms?
I'm looking for an explanation of such behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: What does "it breaks" means? Give us the full python error.

Comment: You just get a regular input field. Like if the choices param is empty.

Comment: Your reverse example contains a bug, since reverse() returns None. Should be: "return reversed(self.category_models.reverse())"

Answer (score 0):

Using a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) field is the way to go if you ask me:

```
class CategoryModel(models.Model):
    pass


class Category(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(CategoryModel)
    pass
```

If you add the CategoryModel in the admin panel, you'll be able to add/remove CategoryModels on a whim.

Having a ForeignKey in a Category model form displays a SELECT input.

Comment: That's one of the things I already thought of, but my approach works for me as I can replace the dummy entry with actual data. I do not think it's needed to keep this in database, as it seems to be too much. Like I said, I'm looking for explanation of the weird behaviour of this.